# CSS IE 9 Issue works fine in Chrome

Tags: css

I have the following CSS based site that looks fine in Chrome, FF and opera but when I test on IE, particularly IE 9 it renders the page flush left instead of center on the page...I can't see where IE is seeing instructions to do this in CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page is rendered in Quircks Mode.

Make the doctype like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

Or add this meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Comment: I added the meta tag, same result...any idea why?

Comment: Add it after the title, not at the end of the head tag.